# Raspberry Pi get data through TCP using Node Red

Tags: tcp, raspberry-pi, node-red

I have a raspberry Pi and I wanted to read data from my RFID Reader that produced output to TCP connection. How do I read the data using Node-red?

Thanks

Comment: We will need a lot more information before we can help here. What have you tried already? What are the details about how the RFID works?

Comment: Its a long range RFID Reader. I have tried using the tcp and udp node in Node Red. But nothing is working. The output from the reader is through tcp

Comment: That really doesn't tell us any more than you have already in the question. Edit the question (don't use comments) to include how you tried to use the TCP in node, which of it's 2 modes did you use?

Comment: It would help if you could successfully get the data directly from the PI with a python script - it's like you're trying to climb two hills at once. Have you talked to the reader with any other method?